# Convert /@<handle> to /users/profile/<handle> with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm looking for an nginx rule that would do this:

```
input url: http://domain.com/@johndoe
what our backend sees: http://domain.com/users/profile/johndoe
```

Example: http://medium.com/@stuartkhall

The current rule I'm using (removed things that don't have to do with this question):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name _;

    root /var/html;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  mainphp;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

**What kind of rule I can add to my current nginx config?** I experimented with a `rewrite` but wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Better practice is location + return instead of rewrite, so try this (place before any location):

```
location ~ ^/@(.*)$ {
    return 301 /users/profile/$1;
}
```

or identical rewrite in case you prefer it

```
rewrite ^/@(.*)$ /users/profile/$1 last;
```